# how to work with genymotion in vt-d processor in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, genymotion

genymotion already installed but when I want to work it will show only a white page of genymotion and nothing will happen. my system has all prerequisites for genymotion except VT-x processor.i have a VT-d processor. How can I work with genymotion in the VT-d processor?